# Unable to Proxy AWS EMR Jupyter-Notebook's socket through node application. Failed to load kernel

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

We have our node application which we want to use to proxy jupyter notebook running on AWS EMR. I am able to proxy all my http request from my node application using **http-proxy-middleware**. But for some reason I am unable to proxy web-socket requests. Because of this I am able to create a new notebook but unable to start the kernel. Here is my proxy middleware

```
'use strict';
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = proxy({
  target: 'http://<EMR master_node IP>:<Port>',
  ws: true,
  changeOrigin: true,
  // onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
  //   proxyReq.removeHeader('Upgrade');
  //   proxyReq.removeHeader('Connection');
  //   proxyReq.setHeader('Upgrade', 'websocket');
  //   proxyReq.setHeader('Connection', 'upgrade');
  // },
  secure: true,
  loglevel: 'debug'
});
```

I tried to manually add the headers as well which you see as commented but it did not help. Also for the server application I have upgrade enabled.

```
server.on('upgrade', proxy.upgrade);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

```
handleRequestHeaders = function (proxyRequest, request) {

    proxyRequest.setHeader('Host', request.headers['host']) ;
    proxyRequest.setHeader('X-Forwarded-For', request.connection.remoteAddress) ;
    proxyRequest.setHeader('X-Real-IP', request.connection.remoteAddress)

    if (request.headers['upgrade']) {
        proxyRequest.setHeader('Upgrade', request.headers['upgrade']) ;
    }

    proxyRequest.setHeader('Connection', request.headers['upgrade'] ? 'upgrade' : 'close') ;

    proxyRequest.setHeader('Referer', 'http://localhost') ;
    proxyRequest.removeHeader('Origin') ;

}

module.exports = proxy({
    target: 'http://<EMR master_node IP>:<Port>',
    ws: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq: handleRequestHeaders,
    onProxyReqWs handleRequestHeaders
});
```